# Dynamic Sender Profile in Marketing Cloud: Sender address wrong and failure to send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

In Salesforce Marketing Cloud, I have set up a dynamic sender. In a block content, I have inserted the following AMPscript code:

```
    %%[
set @CampaignMemberCommonId = AttributeValue("CampaignMember:Common:Id")
if not empty(@CampaignMemberCommonId) then   
    set @OwnerId = Lookup("Journey_01MarchTestLP_20230301T072855312", "CampaignMember:Common:OwnerId", "CampaignMember:Common:Id", @CampaignMemberCommonId)    
    if not empty(@OwnerId) then
        set @users = LookupRows("userSalesforce","Id", @OwnerId)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@users)
        if rowcount(@users) > 0 then
   var @userName, @userEmail
   set @user = row(@users,1) /* get row #1 */
            set @userName = Field(@user, "Name", 0)
            set @userEmail = Field(@user, "Email", 0)
        endif
    endif    
    set @defaultFromName = "Default Name"
    set @defaultFromAddress = "default@example.com"
    if not empty(@userEmail) then
        set @fromName = @userName
        set @fromAddress = @userEmail
    else
        set @fromName = @defaultFromName
        set @fromAddress = @defaultFromAddress
    endif
endif
]%%
```

I set the following in the profile sender:

- **From Name:** `%%[ContentBlockByKey("dynamicFromNameEmailCode")]%% %%=v(@fromName)=%%`
- **From Address:** `%%[ContentBlockByKey("dynamicFromNameEmailCode")]%%    %%=v(@fromAddress)=%%`

Everything looks correct but:

- In the test, only one user's records receive emails (there are two
  users).
- Emails are received from an email address other than the one
  specified in @userAddress

Any ideas?

Comment: The email address was rendered from `@userEmail` would need to be verified first in order to use as "From Address" in the dynamic sender profile. Go to Email Studio >> Admin >> From Address Management to check if the email address was verified or not, if not try to verify it and try again.

Comment: Hi Duc,
thank you for your reply.
I tried yesterday after verifying the users' email addresses. One works, the other doesn't (but I think it's an address domain issue).

Comment: Hi Antonio, are both email addresses verified? Just go to the direction I mentioned above to check. Then I would try to make a test send using the email address that currently doesn't work to see if I could receive the email or not

Comment: Test done! Email was not sent. In this test, the user's email address is @yahooo.com: could this be the problem?

Comment: Since that email address isn't a real email address so I doubt if you could verify it in MC system. Try go to Email Studio >> Admin >> From Address Management and then add that email address and verify it, you will see

Comment: It is a real address, and it has been verified (please see the link to [img](https://ssg-f-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/68000004E2Ts/a/68000000fhSQ/v5Jw9RrUwhkRbfFggSfIKkPCSIRLUZAozr7XN_VtnfQ) ). However, I cannot send emails from this address. I didn't explain it well in my previous comment. My apologize.

Comment: Have you checked the subscriber status yet? If the subscriber record is having a unsubscribed status and you are doing a commercial send, then they won't receive